# Is there a way to automate crop tending?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I am in control of mostly all of the fields in the game including a few greenhouses that need watering/tending as well. They are all usually growing something, too (except flowers because reasons)

Is there any pet, combo, or friend I can make to help with the watering and general tending work of all or at least some of the fields? I'm currently in early summer year 2.